# Recurrence equation and differential equation in one

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

In a linear algebra exam I can across the following question.

> Determine the general solution of the differential equations
>   $$
> \begin{pmatrix}
> \dot x_{n+1}\\
> \dot y_{n+1}\\
> \dot z_{n+1}
> \end{pmatrix}=
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 6&3&3\\
> 3&6&3\\
> 3&3&6
> \end{pmatrix}
> \begin{pmatrix}
> x_{n}\\
> y_{n}\\
> z_{n}
> \end{pmatrix}.
> $$

Now in class, we'd previously seen how to solve DEs and recurrence relations using diagonalisation, however I've never seen a problem which was *both* a DE and a recurrence relation.

How does one even interpret the problem, notationally speaking? I think it means that the derivative of the $(n+1)$st vector is given by the product of the matrix with the previous vector. So presumably one would first have to solve it as a DE, then as a recurrence relation? Or the other way around?

Comment: What is the initial condition for the recurrence? Do you know the functional form of $x_0$, $y_0$, and $z_0$?

Comment: @stochastic No, only this. Do you think it could be a mistake?